# On Windows, WSASend fails with WSAENOBUFS

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, tcp

On Windows XP when I am calling *WSASend* in iterations on non-blocking socket, it fails with WSAENOBUFS.

I've two cases here:

**Case 1:**

On non-blocking socket I am calling *WSASend*. Here is pseudo-code:

```
while(1)
{
    result = WSASend(...); // Buffersize 1024 bytes
    if (result == -1)
    {
        if (WSAGetLastError() == WSAENOBUFS)
        {
            // Wait for some time before calling WSASend again
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case WSASend returns sucessfully for around  88000 times. Then it fails with WSAENOBUFS and never recovers even when tried after some time as shown in the code.

**Case 2:**

In order to solve this problem, I referred **[this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/201213)** and as suggested there,
just before above code, I called *setsockopt* with SO_SNDBUF and set buffersize 0 (zero)

In this case, WSASend returns sucessfully for around  2600 times. Then it fails. But after waiting it succeeds again for 2600 times then fails.

Now I've these questions in both the cases:

Case 1:

1. What factors decides this number 88000 here?
2. If the failure was because of TCP buffer was full, why it didn't recover after some time?

Case 2:

1. Again, what factors decides the number 2600 here?
2. As given in Microsoft KB article, if instead of internal TCP buffers it sends from application buffer directly, why would it fail with WSAENOBUFS?

EDIT:

In case of asynchronous sockets (On Windows XP), the behavior is more strange. If I ignore WSAENOBUFS and continued further writing to socket I eventually get disconnection WSAECONNRESET. And not sure at the moment why does that happen?

Comment: You cannot get an answer for this, these are undocumented implementation details of the tcp/ip driver stack.  And the raft of other code that's involved: your virus scanner, your firewall, your proxy, the routers, whatever machine you are connected to, the software it runs.  Undocumentable details.

Comment: Well, all I am looking for is best method to deal with WSAENOBUFS error. May be there are some configurations changes I need to make so that I would not get this error (or at least won't get it so often).

Comment: Using a blocking socket is an obvious workaround.  Non-blocking is only interesting when you've got something else to do.  In which case you typically use overlapped I/O instead, non-blocking sockets were interesting in simpler times.  The rate you can write bytes to a socket always greatly exceeds the rate at which they can get sent, particularly so in an artificial test program.  The error code eventually clears, but it is easy to not wait long enough when there's 88 megabytes left to be sent.  Not reading them at the other end of the wire would be another reason.

Comment: @Andrew why are you using nonblocking sockets anyway? Can't you just switch to async IO? This is basically the standard model for servers with many connections. If you have few connections, just go synchronous.

Comment: @usr: That was interesting and useful suggestion. I found another strange behavior with asynchronous IO. Please see my edit. Tnx.

Comment: @Andrew if the problem is not yet resolved for you you can post the source for the async IO version. Maybe there is something wrong. I have no obvious ideas what it might be, assuming that you only issue one write after the previous has completed (not just the send, but the IO actually completed).

Comment: @usr - switching to async I/O but continuing to follow the original code's design will do nothing to fix the problem - see here: http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/06/tcp-flow-control-and-asynchronous-writes.html

Comment: @LenHolgate I assume you mean that if he is issuing an unlimited number of parallel IOs, the problem will remain. That's true, but that's not how async IO should work. The next send should be started after previous completed. That way the problem goes away, even for an infinitely fast producer. The kernel just delays IO completion when the send buffer is full. Application flow control is not needed here. The stack does that, and no WSAENOBUFS will occur.

Comment: @usr - which is why I said that if he continues to follow the code's original design then switching to async I/O will do nothing to fix the problem. The problem he has is in the design of the code which issues and uncontrolled number of concurrent I/O requests. By the way, only ever having one outstanding overlapped write is not the most efficient way to do overlapped I/O as you will likely never 'fill' the TCP connection's window. Far better to get enough data flowing that the TCP stack starts doing flow control itself, keep the TCP window full but don't try and over-fill.

Comment: @LenHolgate: Yes that is true we have multiple threads processing requests in parallel and once they finish there is callback mechanism that gets called to write those responses one by one to the socket. We are just doing stress test to check limits of the server. Rather than making significant design changes at this stage, what we were thinking is, once we get WSAENOBUFS we will hold writing to the socket and will wait for another callback that tells us previous responses are through. Probably then is it safe to start again to write remaining responses ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The values are undocumented and depend on what's installed on your machine that may sit between your application and the network driver. They're likely linked to the amount of memory in the machine. The limits (most probably non-paged pool memory and i/o page lock limit) are likely MUCH higher on Vista and above.

The best way to deal with the problem is add application level flow control to your protocol so that you don't assume that you can just send at whatever rate you feel like. See [this blog posting](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/06/tcp-flow-control-and-asynchronous-writes.html) for details of how non-blocking and async I/O can cause resource usage to balloon and how you have no control over it unless you have your own flow control.

In summary, never assume that you can just write data to the wire as fast as you like using non-blocking/async APIs. Remember that due to how TCP/IP's internal flow control works you COULD be using an uncontrollable amount of local machine resources and the client is the only thing that has any control over how fast those resources are released back to the O/S on the server machine.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed one :) As a part of stress test I continued writing to socket (which previously had given WSAENOBUFS) and I found eventually I get WSAECONNRESET. Is it intentional by protocol? I'll try although getting it into application level flow as you suggested. May be that will address both the problems?

Comment: If you get to a point where a send returns WSAENOBUFS then your TCP stream is potentially screwed up anyway (especially if your data buffer is larger than system page size) as there's no guarantee from the API that all or none of your data has been sent, all you can do in this situation is abort your connection. Continuing to send is, IMHO, pointless. The best bet is to avoid getting into the situation in the first place by knowing how much data is outstanding on the link and managing it actively before the OS has to step in by running out of resources...

Comment: In asynchronous writes, I can find out how much data I written and via after_write call back out of that how much data has been sent. The difference is outstanding data on link. But the main challenge is how much window is available to write (especially when there is no application flow control in design) so that to avoid WSAENOBUFFS proactively.

Comment: That's not strictly true. You can judge the amount of data that you have written and is pending completion but that amount bears no relation to the total amount of data that is in-flight between peers. The OS will 'complete' an async write when it has finished using your buffer, and this is likely just when the data has been copied into the TCP stack's own buffers. If you have set SO_SNDBUF to 0 on your socket then this MAY be once the data has been acked at the TCP level by the peer (but I haven't tested this and it's undocumented). You don't get any of this from a non-blocking WSASend().

Comment: I assume you never get a WSAWOULDBLOCK from your WSASend()... IMHO using non-blocking WSASend() in this way is just the wrong approach to take. You either need your own flow control OR you should let the OS provide it for you with a blocking send. OR you should use IOCP and use the number of outstanding overlapped writes on the connection as an indicator to give tell you when to slow down. ALL of these approaches likely require that you have some way of queueing (or slowing the production of) data prior to sending. A design which doesn't allow for this is, IMHO, fundamentally broken.

Comment: The Sockets API guarantees that data you have already sent will be queued for transmission, and that data you have just tried to send but got an error on isn't queued. I'm not aware of any reason to believe that WSAENOBUFS => "TCP stream is potentially screwed". It's not mentioned in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx). All it says is "an operation on a socket could not be completed".

Comment: EJP - If you have issued 3 overlapped writes (one after the other), A, B and C and get an error completion for B but not for A or C what does it mean as far as the state of your outgoing TCP stream... How do you recover from the fact that you've successfully sent A and C but not B?