# How to avoid buffer overflow on asynchronous non-blocking WSASend calls

Tags: windows, sockets, networking, asynchronous, tcp

This is regarding TCP server which is being developed on Windows. The server will have thousands of clients connected. And server will continuously keep sending random sized bytes (Lets say anything between 1 to 64KB) to clients in non-blocking asynchronous manner.

Currently I do not have any constraint or condition before I call `WSASend`. I just call it with buffer I got of whatever size, and receive callback (as it is non-blocking call) once data is sent.

The problem is that, if one or few of clients are slow in receiving data, eventually my server's kernel buffer get full and I end up getting buffer overflow (`WSAENOBUFS`) errors afterwards.

To avoid that, I plan to do like this:

If server has (X) size kernel buffer, and if maximum number of clients would be connected is (N) then I'll allow only (X)/(N) bytes to be written on socket of each client.
(Thus for 50K connection and for kernel buffer size 128 MB, I'll write only maximum 2684 bytes at a time to each socket) And once I receive callback, I can send next set of bytes.
This way even if any of or few clients are slow, it will not result in occupying all of kernel buffer with their pending data.

Now questions are:

1. Is it correct approach to do this?
2. If yes, how much

   a. Size of kernel buffer (X), and

   b. Maximum number of connections to be allowed (N),

should be good to go with for optimum performance.

**Note:** This is *not* duplicate of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608645/on-windows-wsasend-fails-with-wsaenobufs) on same issue. But this is more about validating solution I came up after going through its answer and [link](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/06/tcp-flow-control-and-asynchronous-writes.html) I got in answer of the question.

Comment: Can you show your code? I suspect that you are queueing data faster than can be sent over the network. This is a common mistake. It is usually avoided by only having one send outstanding per socket. Only issue the next send once the previous send completed.

Comment: There is nothing in code perspective. You are right, the problem is server sends data faster than receiver reads it. But synchronous sends (as you suggested) would slow it down?

Comment: Another thing is, if thousand of clients are connected then "one send outstanding per socket" would also result in overflow, if buffers are big and network is slow.

Comment: My understanding is that Winsock sends are zero-copy. The kernel locks the user-mode pages into memory and hands out the address to the NIC for sending. The kernel buffers required are not proportional to the number of bytes outstanding. This error usually means that *the number* of operations outstanding is too high.; In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608645/on-windows-wsasend-fails-with-wsaenobufs, do you understand why Case 1 is broken? Just making sure.

Comment: Ohh... I think you have point. That's why even after calling `setsockopt` with SO_SNDBUF and buffer size 0 (zero) it still fails with buffer overflow. Now I can see reason behind it. I'll try what you saying. But do we have it documented anywhere ?

Comment: If you queue an unlimited amount of writes, that will eventually exhaust memory. Each write at least takes one byte of memory. Of course, memory runs out that way eventually. I don't know about documentation of this and frankly I don't care because it cannot work by principle.

Comment: I now see that we have talked about that in the previous question as well. "Application flow control is not needed" - usr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't have multiple `WSASend()` calls outstanding on the same socket.  Maintain your own buffer for outgoing data.  When you put data in the buffer, if the buffer was previously empty then pass the current buffer content to `WSASend()`.  Each time `WSASend()` completes, it tells you how many bytes it sent, so remove that many bytes from the front of the buffer, and if the buffer is not empty then call `WSASend()` again with the remaining content.  While `WSASend()` is busy, if you need to send more data, just append it to the end of your buffer and let `WSASend()` see it when it is ready.

Comment: Avoiding multiple `WSASend()` calls outstanding on same socket seems sensible approach. Many thanks for answer with implementation details. With this I got few buffer overflows under heavy load conditions. When we get callback it tells how many bytes it sent. Do we need to consider that number to decide size of next send. In worst case if it has just sent 1 byte, it would be effectively calling `WSASend` over and again on same socket just after sending a byte ? (Just to consider worst case scenario for perfect solution)

Comment: like I said, each time you call `WSASend()`, just pass the entire buffer, and then the callback will tell you how many bytes were actually sent.  So let's say you put 100 bytes in the buffer.  Send all 100 bytes, and if 1 byte is sent (worse case), you would remove 1 byte from the front of the buffer and send the remaining 99 bytes (or more, if you appended more bytes to the buffer while `WSASend()` was busy).

Comment: Understood. Just trying to find out why in that case it still gives me overflow. But when I confirmed (before calling `WSASend`) no pending bytes on stream (all bytes sent), the overflow seems disappeared. That made me to think calling `WSASend` again on same socket when zero bytes are sent is more or less same as calling it on same socket when one byte is sent.

Comment: `WSASend()` should never report 0 bytes sent. Anything less than 1 byte should be treated as a transmission error.

Comment: In blocking mode WSASend() doesn't return until all bytes have been transferred to the socket send buffer. I don't see any reason for duplicating the function of the socket send buffer like this, and I've never seen a network program that did it, in several decades.

Comment: @EJP: Then I'm guessing you don't do parallel/multithreaded socket programming.  I use `WSASend()` with overlapped sockets and I/O Completion Ports using buffered sends like I described.

Comment: Interesting design. In over 10 years working with IOCP I've never seen an overlapped send completion return anything other than the full amount sent in the WSABUF. What sized buffers are you using here? I assume that you have a fixed sized buffer which is more than the connection's TCP window + optimum additional space for max throughput.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've been doing exactly that for over twenty years actually, and written books about it. *I* am *not* guessing.

Answer (score -1):

Let the error tell you. That's what it's for. Just keep sending *until* you get the error, then stop.

Comment: Long back I had thought the same. But when I did that I observed server started facing problems. So I posted [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19608645/on-windows-wsasend-fails-with-wsaenobufs?lq=1) on SO. Where in answer it was mentioned "If you get to a point where a send returns WSAENOBUFS then your TCP stream is potentially screwed up anyway" Made me to believe its not good practice to go on writing until we get overflow.

Comment: I don't have any confidence in that assertion. The Sockets API guarantees that data you have already sent will be queued for transmission, and that data you have just tried to send but got an error on isn't queued. I'm not aware of any reason to believe that WSAENOBUFS => "TCP stream is potentially screwed". It's not mentioned in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx). All it says is "an operation on a socket could not be completed".

Comment: Thanks. I'll revisit this approach. But after getting `WSAENOBUFS` for certain client shall I stop sending only for that client and continue sending to other clients? OR stop sending altogether for all clients and try after some time (may be after getting callback for one of previous writes)? (Asking this because am not aware whether kernel maintains separate queue for each client or its common one)

Comment: With badly coded drivers the first you know of this error could be non-paged pool exhaustion and process termination or a blue screen.

Comment: @LenHolgate Hard to believe. There is a socket send buffer, of a defined and fixed size, and when it fills further sends should block. Do you have some evidence about your claim?

Comment: @EJP Overlapped WSASends never block. They always succeed and non-paged pool is used from the moment you issue them. See http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/06/tcp-flow-control-and-asynchronous-writes.html. Easy to reproduce the issue. You can also see the same effect with the file system and overlapped file writes that are issued faster than the file system can complete them...